# How to get Chrome to open multiple sites in a new tab

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, tabs

I'm developing a tool that lets you open multiple pages at once with a shortcut, to be used for things like opening your daily sites or querying multiple search engines for a phrase.  In Firefox, Internet Explorer and Opera, assuming you've unblocked pop-ups for the domain, the code works as expected.

Chrome, however, opens the sites in new windows instead of tabs if the links are opened automatically when the page loads.  If openAll() is commented out and the button is clicked or a key is pressed, the pages open in tabs.  Note it's calling the exact same function.

The best solution I've found (which isn't saying much) is the [One Window](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/papnlnnbddhckngcblfljaelgceffobn) extension.  It works, but you can see the new window open then get sucked back in, and it keeps you from opening new Windows with Ctrl-N, forcing you to drag tabs out to use another Chrome window.

I can understand there not being a programmatic way to change this because it's a browser setting, but as a user of the tool it's annoying to have the sites all open in new windows.  Is there a Chrome setting or extension that will open links in tabs when they're loaded without user input?  I realize opening a bevy of windows is the very thing browsers aim to stop, but this is one time where I want to allow it.

```
<input id="openAllBtn" type="button" value="Open all links"> (Or press any key)
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openAll() {
    window.open('http://yahoo.com/');
    window.location.replace('http://www.bing.com/');
    return false;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).bind('keypress', openAll);
    $("#openAllBtn").bind("click", openAll);
    openAll();
});
</script>
```

Here's a Fiddle of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/sfzjR/

Comment: What version of chrome are you using? The jsfiddle you provided opened up 2 tabs in chrome for me.

Comment: Let me try this again.  Here is what I would do to enact the general behavior that you are looking for:
//Create simple `target='_blank'` links for each link you want to open. // Gather all the elements by a common class in jQuery.  // Trigger the click events of each in succession after a certain delay.  // Allow the user to stop the opening of the links by clicking the button again at any time, presumably by killing a setTimeout function. // This has the benefit of not crashing or DOSing the viewer's browser when they click and open 70 links.

Comment: @matzahboy I'm using Chrome 13.0.782.32 beta-m and tested with the latest Chromium dev build.  The fiddle had the call to openAll() commented out.  Try uncommenting it then running it.

Comment: @Tchalvak I could do that, but the issue would still remain - the links would be opened as new Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a Chrome setting or extension
>   that will open links in tabs when
>   they're loaded without user input?

Check out the create method in the [chrome extension docs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html). By default it will open a new tab, you can optionally specify the window you want that tab to open in, and give the tab a url.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I was hoping not to have to create an extension to solve this, but it's looking like it may be the best option.