# Javascript window.open inconsistent in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I give the user an option to open a single tab or a tab group. When they click a special link I would like to open several related tabs. The javascript for opening several tabs is as follows:

```
<li>
  <a href="javascript:launchAll()">Or launch them all at once</a>
</li>

<script>
   function launchAll() {
     var win = window.open("http://domain.com/page1");
     win = window.open("http://domain.com/page2");
     win = window.open("http://domain.com/page3");
     win = window.open("http://domain.com/page4");
   }
</script>
```

The first two open as tabs the second two try to open as popups/in separate windows, which are blocked in my case. Unblocking popups is not the issue and this UI is not the question. My question is why these four seemingly identical calls produce different results.

UPDATE: this only seems to happen in Chrome. Firefox and Safari open all as new tabs. Does anyone know a work around?

Comment: Good question, for me the first three open normally and the third opens in a popup.

Comment: I just tried adding delay before opening the other links and it didn't work... To detect if something is undesired or not, I think Chrome remembers whether the user has clicked not long ago or not. And in your case, the answer is no, hence the fact that they are blocked.

Comment: Try putting _blank as target. I'm nearly sure it won't work but who knows :)
Also, try storing them in different variables. Even though it probably won't work either.

Comment: This might be useful: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511973/how-to-get-chrome-to-open-multiple-sites-in-a-new-tab

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but you don't need to assign window.open(...) to a variable. Feel free to take out the "win = " parts of your code unless you intend to interact with the opened window after you have created it.

Comment: Jed, not all the code is in the question. At one point I was checking return values, which didn't help.


xavierm02, I tried those things but I think Aleksandr has the answer, it is a limitation of Chrome. 


Yes, I know this is not a good UI but given the contraints it is the best I could come up with. The alternative is making the user click a bunch of links, which is available in the UI too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This limitation is actually due to a Chrome security setting: Chrome doesn't want people to be able to open unlimited tabs by just one click.  Therefore, the setting they use is, maximum of two tabs for the first click, one tab for each additional click.  So, if you wanted to get around this, you would have to do something like this:

```
<li>
  <a href="javascript:launchAll()">Or launch them all at once</a>
  <a href="javascript:launch()" id="test"></a>
  <a href="javascript:launch2()" id="test2"></a>
</li>

<script>
   function launchAll() {
     var win = window.open("http://domain.com/page1");
     win = window.open("http://domain.com/page2");
     document.getElementById("test").click();
   }
   function launch(){
     var win = window.open("http://domain.com/page3");
     document.getElementById("test2").click();
   }
   function launch2(){
     var win = window.open("http://domain.com/page4");
   }
</script>
```

Note that since the `<a id="test*">` contents are empty, they won't show up in your document, so your layout stays the same.

Also, note, that the `click()` method does not exist in Firefox, so you would have to use something like [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?161317-Trying-to-get-javascript-to-click-a-link-when-function-is-called&s=86a7aab5b6320355332ef56692defe5a&p=804855#post804855).

Comment: Thanks. This is sort of a kludgey intranet UI. I'm opening pages to compare from several external sites and can't use iframes. I wanted to save the user the trouble of clicking a bunch but all the links are available so they can always do that in Chrome. Ugh.

Comment: This no longer works as of some recent version of Chrome, maybe 25 or 26. http://jsfiddle.net/etjNf/